# How to remove error messages?

Tags: php

I have used this code for removing errors:

```
error_reporting($level = NULL);
```

It gave me a result with blank page. How migh I neglect php errors and load a page normally?

Comment: One technique I find very useful for this is fixing the errors.

Comment: You should fix the errors, if you have a situation maybe has error and you can't treat this with try catch, try to use @ before the method to supress the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
error_reporting(0);
```

or disable error for 1 function - `@function_name();`

Disabling erros is highly discouraged. You should fix errors.

Comment: It's highly recommend you don't use @ in front of things.  The only time this is acceptable is when you are doing an optional operation that might fail and you don't care, such as deleting uploads from a temp folder.

Comment: Of course I am not using any of those. But if he wants solution I can show him but also recommend not to use it

Answer (score 1):

You can set what types of notifications you get using
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

```
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_ERROR|0);
```

and you can toggle if they show or not with
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php

```
ini_set('display_errors','On|Off');
```

and when I write A|B I mean you choose A or B, not both

Answer (score 0):

use `error_reporting(0);`

it will suppress all the errors on  the page...

and to suppress an error that can occur on a specific statement such as database loading..

you can use.. `@`

eg:

`$db = @mysqli_query($dbc, '....query....');`

It will solve your problem..

Comment: No. It will _conceal_ the problem. The problem will still be there.

Comment: You were answering the question, which is why I didn't downvote. But suppressing errors from functions is bad practice, and your answer doesn't mention that.

Comment: please read the question again. I think my answer justify the question. what are you trying to say in your first line. 'which is why i didn't downvote'. First learn to answer then try make these type of comments.

Comment: I've read the question. You have answered it. Your answer does not mention that suppressing error messages is bad practice. I added a note saying so.